# CSS after mouse is moved from hover

Tags: html, css, css-animations

In CSS, the hover event is triggering as it should. However, when it is an animation, when the mouse is moved back off the object (in this case a button), it returns to its normal state without an animation back. This results in it looking really jumping and going against the theme I'm shooting for. So, I need an event that is triggered after the hover event, like what I thought would work: `.button-default:hover:after {}`, but didn't work the way I expected. My CSS below:

```
.button-default {
    width: 40vw;
    height: 5vh;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: white;
}

.button-default:hover {
    animation-name: animate-button;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.button-default:hover:after {
    animation-name: normalize-button;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes normalize-button {
    from {
        color: blue;
        background: white;
        border-color: blue;
    }
    to {
        width: 40vw;
        height: 5vh;
        color: white;
        background: transparent;
        border: solid 2px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-color: white;
    }
}

@keyframes animate-button {
    from {
        .button-default;
    }
    to {
        color: blue;
        background: white;
        border-color: blue;
    }
}

body {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    /*background: url('../images/novam.png') no-repeat center;*/
    background: black;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I think you have a miss concept on the :after in css. It means what is shown after the box model for the element. It is not a Time action as I think  you trying here.

Comment: I realize that now, but every document I read made it sound like it fired as an event in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your animation only need two stages, you can just use css transition instead of animation to get that effect. And FYI, after is pseudo element. It is not event.

```
.button-default {
    width: 40vw;
    height: 5vh;
    color: white;
    background: transparent;
    border: solid 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: white;
     -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    transition: all 2s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 2s ease; 
}

.button-default:hover {
        color: blue;
    background: white;
    border-color: blue;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThetHlaing10/tjx3g65r/) here